# Non-auto-increment rails/postgresql column

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql-9.1

I'm trying to have a model/table with duplicate information in it. The reason for this is so that the same data can be written to the table under different users and found for each user. However, I want a quick easy way to identify which information is a duplicate of other information. I think the best way to do this would be to have an item_id of sorts that increments with each "set" of entries to the table. Is there a way to do this without including another table that stores the information without attributing it to users?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually what I was looking for was a PostgreSQL Sequence. Here's the code I ended up using in my migration

```
def up
  ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("create sequence action_id_seq;")
end

def down
  ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("drop sequence action_id_seq;")
end
```

And then when querying I use

```
Action.find_by_sql("SELECT NEXTVAL('action_id_seq') AS action_id").first.event_id
```

For my purposes this works fairly well and I can use it to have a unique ID for which I control the increment.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would set your associations up:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :records
end


class Record < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :user :foreign_key => user_id
end
```

Then you will have to set the user_id attribute to the id of the current_user before saving the Record.

You can retrieve the rows by:

```
User.first.records
Record.first.user
```

Comment: This isn't quite what I'm looking for. The "sets" are not defined by user but defined by the action that creates the data. So for example, a user writing a post on a blog would generate two records, each containing the same data, but one whose owner_id was the user and one whose owner_id was the product. I want to assign these two records a unique ID

Comment: please include your existing model and the create action so we can have a better understanding.